# Encountering a SQL Error 40001 in Dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm doing a count * query that executes correctly but for some reason when I attempt to export it to CSV, I'm encountering a SQL Error [40001]. Any ideas what the issue could be?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a long query on a standby server, and some modifications that are replicated from the primary server conflict with your query. In particular, `VACUUM` removed some old row versions that your query still might want to use.

PostgreSQL has to make a choice: either delay applying the changes from the primary, or cancel the query that blocks replication.

How PostgreSQL behaves is determined by the parameter `max_standby_streaming_delay`. The default value gives the query 30 seconds to finish before it is canceled.

You have three options:

1. Retry the query and hope it succeeds this time.
2. Increase `max_standby_streaming_delay` on the standby.

   The risk you are running is that replication will fall behind.
3. Set the parameter `hot_standby_feedback` to `on` on the standby, then the primary won't `VACUUM` row versions the standby might still need.

   The risk you are running is table bloat on the primary, because autovacuum cannot do its job.